# Проблема отображения компонентов в конструкторе C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

возникла проблема с отображение личных компонентов в конструкторе C# WPF.
Написал свой компонент, подключаю его и в конструкторе он не отображается должным образом, но при запуске программы все отображается.
[image: Ошибка отображения]

Я полазил по разным настройкам и был один вариант на странице [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2017/xaml-tools/debugging-or-disabling-project-code-in-xaml-designer?view=vs-2017#control-display-options)

Рекомендовали включить данный пункт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не помогло. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: ПКМ - Очистить проект, ПКМ - Пересобрать проект. Если не помогает, то еще удалите папки obj и bin. А вообще, забудьте про него, запустите под отладкой проект, и пишите глядя как на живом проекте все будет выглядеть.

Comment: Это крайние варинаты и начинать можно не с них. @EvgeniyZ

Comment: @rotabor Это самый первый вариант, который **надо** делать. XAML обновляет данные о новых контролах, стилях, и др. только **после успешной сборки** проекта, сохраняется это все в папке obj. Так что, любое изменение в XAML (будь то создание нового контрола, или стиля), должно сопровождаться первым делом пересборкой проекта. Ну а уже на основе полученной информации после этих действий, делать что-то (например, может выдать конкретную ошибку, которую надо устранить). Напомню, вы не лезете ко мне - я не лезу к вам, дальнейший спор с вами устраивать не собираюсь.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да я с вами и не спорю. Предложил свой вариант решения, который можно испробовать до  крайних мер.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да этот метод помог но буквально до следующего обновления кода компонента (xaml)

Comment: Как и сказал выше, любое изменение в C# коде должно быть сопровождаться **успешным** полным пересбором проекта, тогда XAML обновится, перегенерирует все нужное, и будет отображать. Увы и ах, в WPF он работает так криво, из-за чего многие не пользуются конструктором вовсе, запускают проект, и пишут XAML ручками, это куда удобней, чем пользоваться конструктором, попробуйте)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть в конструкторе компонента. Если вы туда добавили что-то, то это может привести к описываемой неработоспособности. Нужно убрать всё из конструктора и вынести в отдельный метод или другой конструктор с каким-то параметром, чтобы его сигнатура была отлична от стандартного.